# Interpreter will not finish processing code; any error in code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just starting learning Ruby I am using the cloud9.ide to process my Ruby code. The algorithm I am trying to solve asks "write a method to return the largest word in a string." My code:

```
def longest_word(sentence)
new_array = sentence.split(' ')
i = 0
longest_length = 0
while i < new_array.length
    if new_array[i].length > longest_length
         longest_length = new_array[i].length

    end
end

return longest_length

end

print longest_word("My name")
```

I then run the code in cloud9 and for some reason it just keeps going and never finishes processing it like its an infinite loop or something. Is there something wrong with my code or maybe its the interpreter?

Comment: `i` is not incremented in the `while` loop. Forever spinning. Alternatively, `new_array` could be shortened at each iteration, but that looks weird.

Comment: Also welcome to ruby. Instead of doing a while loop check out the each method on the array class, it's an easy way to iterate over an entire collection.

Comment: @Eric Platon you are right! I'm used to using javascript where the for loop is so much easier. i have never used any while loops in javascript than i have ruby and i forgot to increment by 1..

Comment: @CWitty Thank you! And yes, i have looped at the each method and it is easier but since I am a beginner Rubyist, I wanted to do it without any sort of already predefined methods. In javascript they call the each method a callback function/method. I just want to see what I'm doing or at least get the syntax down before I take shortcuts.